# how to take the file names from folder

Tags: shell, scripting

i want to write a program for the below logic:

- Take the names of files in a folder
- For each file:

  - print file name
  - move the file to another new folder (with the name in `dd_mm_yy` format)

Answer (score 1):

To get file name from its full path, you can use [basename](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/utilities/basename.html):

```
$ basename /home/cuonglm/test.pl 
test.pl
```

So you can do something like:

```
for f in *; do
  filename="$(basename -- "$f")"
  # Do sftuff here
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.
I assume that you want the destination filename to be the modification time of the file, and you don't care about the file's original name. Please correct me if it is wrong.

Bash script. Usage: `./script.sh original_dir dest_dir`

```
#!/bin/bash
find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -exec bash -c '
echo "$1"
export LANG=C
name=$(stat -c "%y" . | sed -r  "s/..(..)-(..)-(..).*/\3-\2-\1/")
mv -iT $0 '"$1"'/"$name"' "{}" \;
```